# Elements with fixed position renders slowly on Safari iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, css, css-position

I have a responsive website that uses a menu with position fixed on mobile devices.

In Safari on iPhone the menu seems to be rendered slower than the other content. I want it render at the same speed. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Hard to comment a solution without any real code, but you may want to take a look at: http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/ also you may want to take a look at the network tab in chrome/firefox developer tools.

Comment: Cubsink: I've added a link to an own example showing the issue

Comment: Which iOS are you testing against?  I've tried the page on my 5S running 7.0.3, but I'm not noticing any delayed rendering.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the header and the body to appear at the same time? It is like the header appears after the rest of the page has loaded.

Comment: @tedmiston I am getting this in IOS7 myself but on iPhone 4.

Comment: @Douglas Yes, I want them to appear at the same time.

Comment: One can see Mobile Safari's problem by comparing
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/
with
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/ .

Load the page and look at nav bar when reloading the page.
The fixed nav bar disappears for one moment.

Comment: The problem went away with iOS 8, because Safari uses new faster WKWebView. See also my edited answer below...

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem while page loading.
After hours of testing, I find out that the problem occurs on page unload!
The problem is related to WebKit under iOS (Mobile Safari & Chrome).
Elements with `position: fixed`, `position: device-fixed` or `position: sticky` disappear on page unload.

see also [Fixed positioned elements disappear on page unload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30098000/fixed-positioned-elements-disappear-on-page-unload)

**EDIT:**

I stick into it...

Fixed elements are lifted to a *composited layer*
and there is a corresponding bug on page unload.

From http://newscentral.exsees.com/item/528d72c6d22fab46e4eb18e5cb8fece0-0d5a1eca143f58f995dc015e265514cb:

> "[...] composited layers upon document unload are destroyed much faster than
>   elements that are not [...] This has been confirmed by a WebKit engineer to be a bug."

**HOPE:**

With iOS 8 a new faster web view component was introduced: `WKWebView`.
Safari use it. The problem went away when using Safari :)

I compare common `UIWebView` and new `WKWebView` under iOS 8.
Apps using `UIWebView` to display html/web content are still affected with the problem :(

Answer (score -1):

One of classic CSS optimisation for elements with a position:fixed, is too put it on a layer. You will avoid the repaint of this zone, when user scroll. To do this, you can add use 3d transform, like this :

```
nav {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF0000;
    height: 30px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Don't forget to add all vendor prefixes.
You can enable "show paint rectangle" on Chrome dev tools, to show all repaints off your page.

Comment: The problem though isn't that it repaints when I scroll. The problem is that it seems to render slower than the rest of the content on page load.